# loop errors in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

In angular I've tying to loop my given errors and show them in alert but it doesn't work, I've read and tried different solutions such as using `lenght` or `lenght+1` etc. none of them seem to work.

## Data

```
{name: Array(1), email: Array(1), password: Array(1)}
email: ["The email field is required."]
name: ["The name field is required."]
password: ["The password field is required."]
__proto__: Object
```

## Code

```
error => {
        let errors = error.error.errors;
        console.log(errors); //return result above
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
          this.alertService.presentToast(errors[i]);
        }
      },
```

any idea?

Comment: Could you please console `errors[i]` and check what is the output?

Comment: @KaustubhKhare nothing prints

Comment: To print the above response, you need to maintain same response for all the fields that your are getting from response. Your key is not same, it is changing.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare response coming from server so based on fields that i fill, i get different kind of errors. `The content doesn't matter` the matter is that i can `loop and show that content` what ever it is.

Comment: The response is not an array, it is a json object. So can not loop it through. If you console `errors.name[0]` below your console and above for loop then it will print output.

Answer (score 4):

Hi there are two ways to print the error messages. Hope it may help full for you

1.

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(errors)) {
    console.log(value[0]);
}
```

2.

```
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(errors)) {
    for(let msg of value) {
        console.log(msg);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this

```
Object.keys(errors).forEach(key => {
    alert(errors[key][0]);
});
```